# Compressing extremely large files for archiving purposes on computing cluster - best practice?

Tags: compression, archive, large-data, large-files, hpc

I am in the following situation:

**Current status:**

- ~40TB of data has to be archived
- Mostly [netCDF](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/)4 file format, but folders contain some text files
- No files larger than ~100MB

**Plan:**

- Compress and archive data in a "manageable" way
- The final archive should be pretty accessible when needed, at least after a few hours of decompression on a fairly powerful machine -> essentially a backup or for a one-time transfer
- Compression rate should be good for these files since this is simulation data output which contains quite a few empty data fields here and there
- I am worried about having a singular archive file that is several TB large, so splitting that is probably the way to go (correct me if I am wrong)

Now, with a little bit of googling and thinking I found several methods on how to do exactly that but I would like to have your opinion on a **best-practice procedure** since I have not found too much on that considering these file sizes.

***EDIT:***

- The file format is netCDF4 (the root group attributes give `NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5`). I am not sure if those are compressed already, but a simple `tar -cvzf nctar.tar ncfile.nc` reduces their size by factor ~2.5
- Command I would go with for now is `tar -cvzf --tape-length=2097000 --file=run_archive-{0..2000}.tar dir`
- I am not necessarily asking for an opinion on the best way to do it but better alternatives (better compression? compression in parallel? compatibility?) or pitfalls to avoid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask a more focused question. You state most of the files are netCDF. Typically these already compressed. You also don't tell us anything about what netCDF format you are working with. Also, please tell us what you have done so far. Opinion based questions are strictly speaking not allowed.

Comment: @RobertWilson I added some information to the question to address your concerns. I understand that this might be leading to an opinion-based answer, but I hope the answer to my question would be a or multiple options commonly used to deal with archiving large chunks of data

Comment: If you like to get to the smallest destination space, consider trying different algorithms with high compression levels specified as a setting to the algorithm, check gzip/z/zstd/lz4 hc/brotli. Run a few experiments and see which one performs better. The harder it is to compress, the slower the process will be. Most of them will support splitting the archive into chunks. It's difficult to suggest something better than giving it a shot and doing a few experiments with the data at hand. If you run each experiment on a subset of data, you could approximate what the end result will be.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar problem a few years ago, and I can provide some tips. Please note that my goal here is twofold:

- to make data management relatively easy
- to save as much space as possible at the same time

First, your data. I'm surprised you managed to get extra compression from HDF5, but that is a good thing. Depending on what's inside the files you might or might not want to convert them to regular CSVs to access archived data directly at later stages. The resulting numerical data compression rate is roughly format-agnostic, thus it's all about convenience.

Second, do *not* store everything in a single file. Even compressed that's going to be a ~16TB archive. Your access/compression/decompression times will be completely out of bounds. Also, even with error correction you get a single point of failure. Do not split it into chunks either, the main rule here is one archive per one directory of a reasonable size.

Third, parallel compression is your friend, but see the passage above. You need to keep in mind that you usually use a single or even a master node to do this, and they should be able to handle this.

Finally, let's talk about compression rates. Do not try to save every little bit of space you have. The chance is you'll get another 2-3% at the cost of many-fold increase in the compression time. Try it on a small sample and see if that's what you find acceptable.

This is not *the best* practice since there is no such thing, however, it worked for me on a national-scale cluster for years. All the data was compressed and easily accessible from any machine at any time.